# SQL Server: having issues inserting/updating values with if statements in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Everything before the first check BSW alarm executes correctly. Anything being evaluated by the else/if statements doesn't seem to run the insert statements on the prod library table and I'm not sure why.

I have to pass a lot of variables this way because I'm sourcing the data not from a database. I have tested the queries separately to the stored procedure (insert statements) and they work fine, so it's not a null restriction issue or anything like that.

This is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Truck_Offload]
    @Contract int,
    @Source int,
    @Product int,
    @Truck_Ticket int,
    @Truck_Volume bigint,
    @Flow_weighted_Dens real,
    @Avg_meter_temp real,
    @Avg_meter_press real,
    @fast_loop_dens real,
    @offload_date_year int,
    @offload_date_month int,
    @offload_date_day int,
    @offload_date_hour int,
    @offload_date_min int,
    @BSW real,
    @BSW_alarm bit,
    @BOL bigint,
    @library_ID bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @offload_datetime date;
    DECLARE @temp_result int;
    --DECLARE @contract_to_use int;
    DECLARE @source_to_use int;
    DECLARE @product_string nchar(10);
    DECLARE @density_min real;
    DECLARE @density_max real;
    DECLARE @density_temp real;
    DECLARE @Offload_ID bigint;
    DECLARE @request_ID bigint;
    DECLARE @library_ID_temp int;
    DECLARE @offload_total int;
    DECLARE @offload_max int;
    DECLARE @lib_ID_temp bigint;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --If sample is to be purged, library_ID will be 0
    SELECT @library_ID = 0;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @offload_datetime = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@offload_date_year, @offload_date_month,@offload_date_day, @offload_date_hour, @offload_date_min, 0, 0);

    ---find if contract exists
    SELECT @temp_result = Contract 
    FROM Offload_Contracts
    WHERE Contract = @Contract;

    --if it doesn't exist, add contract
    IF @temp_result = NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @temp_result = eOne_ID 
        FROM Src_Locations
        WHERE eOne_ID = @Source;

        IF @temp_result = NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Src_Locations (eOne_ID) 
            VALUES (@Source);

            SELECT @source_to_use = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            --The name of a new Source Location will be unknown and need to be modified in a GUI.
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @source_to_use = @temp_result;
        END

        --SELECT PRODUCT TO USE FOR NEW CONTRACT
        SELECT @product_string = CASE @Product
                                        WHEN 1 THEN  'C3+'
                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'C5+'
                                        ELSE 'C5+'
                                 END;

        --CREATE NEW CONTRACT
        INSERT INTO Offload_Contracts (Contract, Offload_ID, Product, Source_ID)
        VALUES (@Contract, 1, @product_string, @source_to_use);
    END
    
    -- Use Contract, establish new Offload_Registry Entry. First Insert Truck_Ticket.
    INSERT INTO truck_tickets (Offload_Volume, UOM, Flow_weighted_Dens, meter_average_temp, truck_average_press, fast_loop_dens, offload_date, BSW, BSW_alarm, sys_ticket)
    VALUES (@Truck_Volume, 'm3', @Flow_weighted_Dens, @Avg_meter_temp, @Avg_meter_press, @fast_loop_dens, @offload_datetime, @BSW, 
    , @Truck_Ticket);

    --Now that Truck Ticket has been created, create offload Registry
    INSERT INTO OffLoad_Registry (Offload_Contract, BOL, truck_ticket)
        SELECT @Contract, @BOL, SCOPE_IDENTITY(); --SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the truck_ticket_number

    -- Have the Offload ID handy for later
    SELECT @Offload_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    --NOW we need to do logic to determine whether to keep or purge the sample
    
    --First Check if there was a BSW alarm
    IF @BSW_alarm = 1 AND @Product = 2
    BEGIN
        --create new library record
        INSERT INTO Prod_Library (Offload_ID, Lab_Status) 
        VALUES (@Offload_ID, 'Waiting');

        SELECT @library_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        UPDATE Offload_Contracts 
        SET offload_total = 1
        WHERE Contract = @Contract;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --check if there's been any retain requests made against the contract fed to the stored procedure
        SELECT @request_ID = Request_ID 
        FROM Retain_Requests 
        WHERE Contract = @Contract;

        --if there's a retain request, automatically create a library record
        IF @request_ID <> NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Prod_Library (Offload_ID, Lab_Status) 
            VALUES (@Offload_ID, 'Waiting');

            SELECT @library_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            --update contract
            UPDATE Offload_Contracts 
            SET offload_total = 1
            WHERE Contract = @Contract;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --check if there's a density + origin + contract against the library
            SELECT @lib_ID_temp = P.Lib_ID
            FROM dbo.Prod_Library P
            LEFT JOIN Offload_Registry OfR ON P.Offload_ID = Ofr.Offload_ID
            LEFT JOIN Offload_Contracts OC ON Ofr.Offload_Contract = OC.Contract                
            WHERE Ofr.Offload_Contract = @Contract 
              AND (Lab_Status = 'Waiting' Or Lab_Status = 'Approved');

            IF @lib_ID_temp = NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Prod_Library (Offload_ID, Lab_Status) 
                VALUES (@Offload_ID, 'Waiting');

                SELECT @library_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
            END

            --contract will be updated for offload total if the operator follows the recommendation
            ELSE
            --check retention criteria
            BEGIN
                --get retention criteria
                SELECT @offload_total = OC.offload_total, @density_temp = TT.Flow_weighted_Dens, @density_min = Density_Min, @density_max = Density_Max, @offload_max = Truck_offloads
                FROM Prod_Library AS PL
                INNER JOIN Offload_Registry OFR ON PL.Offload_ID = OFR.Offload_ID
                INNER JOIN truck_tickets TT ON OFR.truck_ticket = TT.Ticket
                INNER JOIN Offload_Contracts OC ON OC.Contract = OFR.Offload_Contract
                INNER JOIN Products Prod ON Prod.Product = OC.Product
                WHERE PL.Lib_ID = @lib_ID_temp;

                IF @offload_total >= @offload_max OR @Flow_weighted_Dens < @density_temp - @density_min OR @Flow_weighted_Dens > @density_temp + @density_max
                -- Retain sample if this is true
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Prod_Library (Offload_ID, Lab_Status) 
                    VALUES (@Offload_ID, 'Waiting');

                    SELECT @library_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                    UPDATE Offload_Contracts 
                    SET offload_total = 1
                    WHERE Contract = @Contract;
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    -- update contracts offload total, sample will be purged
                    UPDATE Offload_Contracts 
                    SET offload_total += 1
                    WHERE Contract = @Contract;
                END
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Calling code was like this, and the return value was always 0.

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[Truck_Offload] 
   @Contract = @Contract
  ,@Source = @Source
  ,@Product = @Product
  ,@Truck_Ticket = @Truck_Ticket
  ,@Truck_Volume = @Truck_Volume
  ,@Flow_weighted_Dens = @Flow_weighted_Dens
  ,@Avg_meter_temp = @Avg_meter_temp
  ,@Avg_meter_press = @Avg_meter_press
  ,@fast_loop_dens = @fast_loop_dens
  ,@offload_date_year = @offload_date_year
  ,@offload_date_month = @offload_date_month
  ,@offload_date_day = @offload_date_day
  ,@offload_date_hour = @offload_date_hour
  ,@offload_date_min = @offload_date_min
  ,@BSW = @BSW
  ,@BSW_alarm = @BSW_alarm
  ,@BOL = @BOL
  ,@library_ID = @library_ID OUTPUT

  SELECT @library_ID;
```

--This Question has been solved, see comments about NULL statements. Thank you Sean.

Comment: Because nothing ever equals NULL. If you want to check for NULL you would need to use something like `IF @temp_result IS NULL`.

Comment: Slight detour....do you have values large enough here that you need to use the `real` datatype? That is an approximate datatype that is absolutely massive. Most of the time using a numeric is more than sufficient. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Oh so I have written both statments with NULL incorrectly I assume? so IS NULL and IS NOT NULL?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Likely not. I could use a numeric datatype. I'm actually pulling values over a PLC card which is why I'm driving a stored procedure like this in the first place (i'm not a DBA). I'll just have to see if the REAL datatype can be cast from the card to the stored procedure as a numeric.

Comment: This worked. How do I change your answer to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that nothing ever equals NULL. It will always evaluate to false. The solution is to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

You have a couple locations in the code you posted where you would need to change this to work the way you want it to.

So IF @temp_result = NULL would need to be rewritten as:

```
IF @temp_result IS NULL
```

and IF @request_ID <> NULL would become:

```
IF @request_ID IS NOT NULL
```

You have a couple other places that match the same pattern and the same solution will correct those as well.